# INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored proc spGetSites that returns three columns for SiteName, SiteId and UnitCount. The stored proc runs perfectly fine. 
I'm trying to store the results of the stored proc to a temp table @Site to use for my report with below syntax. This time I got an error message: "INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested"

Can I not use INSERT and EXEC statement at the same time?

```
DECLARE @Site TABLE (SiteName VARCHAR(100), SiteId INT, UnitCount INT)

INSERT INTO @Site
EXEC spGetSites @SiteId = 0
```

Comment: You should, https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=badf19ac4abc84d32b3aae254074967e Please add you stored procedure to the question, and tag your SQL Server version.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the code for your `spGetSites` procedure, somewhere in that procedure is another `INSERT...EXEC`. It may be directly in that procedure, or nested in the bowels of some other procedure it calls.

Ultimately, if a stored procedure uses `INSERT...EXEC` then if you try to call that stored procedure in the context of another `INSERT...EXEC` you will get the error you are seeing.

### How do you fix it?

1. You could simply take the inner `INSERT...EXEC` and inline the code to this single stored procedure. Though, I suspect that other procedure may be there for a reason: ie to keep your code DRY.
2. Since this is a `Get` procedure, hopefully there's no data manipulation happening anywhere in the call stack. You could convert the child procedure into a table-valued function. This would allow you to convert that inner `INSERT...EXEC` into an `INSERT...SELECT` and resolve this issue.
3. Use temp tables scoped to the outer procedure to pass data between procedures. This solution gets complicated, so it's not my favorite, and I generally discourage this pattern when there's a better option--but for the sake of completeness, I'll include it here.  Basically, if you create your #temp table outside `spGetSites` you can use it inside `spGetSites` (without creating it inside there), and the table with data inserted will survive the procedure execution and continue to work.

I don't like option 3 because it's a coding pattern complex enough to ensure someone messes it up in the future, unless everyone is on board and familiar with the coding pattern:
* `spGetSites` will fail unless you create the table first. All callers need to remember to create the table exactly the same first.
* `spGetSites` can't assume the table is empty. It might have existing data from the outer call (or a prior execution from the same caller)
* Troubleshooting and debugging (and even getting a query plan) for `spGetSites` is more complex because of the table creation confusion.

### What would I do?

Without knowing how complex the code is behind `spGetSites`, I'd look into creating an inline TVF that replaces the inner `INSERT...EXEC` with `INSERT...SELECT` or possibly all of `spGetSites` could be simplified/rewritten to make it self contained without the `INSERT...EXEC`